# ASP.NET Session becomes null after postback on local

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my code that runs on page load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DisableChaching();
    if (Request.Cookies["UserName"] == null)
    {
        if (Session["UserName"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
        }
        else if (Session["AccessLevel"].ToString().Equals("2"))
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
        }
    }
    else if (Session["AccessLevel"].ToString().Equals("2"))
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
    }
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadControls();
        BindGrid();
    }
}
```

Sometimes when I try to save some data to database and I get an error, I try to *re-save* the data by clicking my save button, and I get this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

on the following line if code:

```
else if (Session["AccessLevel"].ToString().Equals("2"))
```

Why am I getting this error?

here is my code in Login user control where ChR is the checkbox to remember the user :

```
if (ChR.Checked == true)
            {
                Response.Cookies["UserName"].Value = txtUserName.Text.Trim();
                Response.Cookies["UserName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);
                Response.Cookies["AccessLevel"].Value = member.AccessLevel.ToString();
                Response.Cookies["AccessLevel"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);
                Response.Cookies["FirstName"].Value = member.FirstName;
                Response.Cookies["FirstName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);
                Response.Cookies["LastName"].Value = member.LastName;
                Response.Cookies["LastName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);
                Session["UserName"] = txtUserName.Text.Trim();
                Session["AccessLevel"] = member.AccessLevel.ToString();
                Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Session["UserName"] = txtUserName.Text.Trim();
                Session["AccessLevel"] = member.AccessLevel.ToString();
                Session["FirstName"] = member.FirstName;
                Session["LastName"] = member.LastName;
                Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
            }
```

and in my master page I assign values to sessions this way in the page_Load event:

```
DisableChaching();
    FillInfo();
    if (Request.Cookies["UserName"] != null)
    {
        Session["UserName"] = Request.Cookies["UserName"].Value;
        Session["AccessLevel"] = Request.Cookies["AccessLevel"].Value;
        Session["FirstName"] = Request.Cookies["FirstName"].Value;
        Session["LastName"] = Request.Cookies["LastName"].Value;
        WellCome();
        if (Session["AccessLevel"].ToString() == "1")
        {
            RenderMenu(AcccessLevel.SiteManager);
        }
        else if (Session["AccessLevel"].ToString() == "2")
        {
            RenderMenu(AcccessLevel.Client);
        }
    }
    else if (Session["UserName"] != null)
    {
        WellCome();
        if (Session["AccessLevel"].ToString() == "1")
        {
            RenderMenu(AcccessLevel.SiteManager);
        }
        else if (Session["AccessLevel"].ToString() == "2")
        {
            RenderMenu(AcccessLevel.Client);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        WellGo();
        RenderMenu(AcccessLevel.LogedOutUser);
    }
enter code here
```

Comment: Did you read this post http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=220827?

Comment: Joe had'nt you have such problem befor ?! that might bring you an idea what could be wrong ? do you see any thing wrong with my code here ? and also here is my code to set session values :

Comment: Maybe you're losing the session because the app-domain recycles. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/08/02/asp-net-case-study-lost-session-variables-and-appdomain-recycles.aspx

Comment: @khashayar - Please up-vote and accept the answer which addresses your problem correctly. This also helps other community users which faces similar issues.

Comment: @Guest unfortunatly I registered in this website recently and I don't have enough reputation to vote ! If you would vote up my question I think I will get some reputation to vote up the answer ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I found out why my sessions become null ! when I want to save info about a book in db and save an image file of the book in an app folder , I don't have the permission to save the file and my application throws an error and all my sessions become null !!!

Comment: That means, if there is any application error session is becoming null!

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code like below.

```
string val = Convert.ToString(Session["AccessLevel"]);
if (val == "2")
{

}
```

I hope you understand the difference between `==` and `Equals()`

```
public static String AccessLevel {
    get
    {
        return Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Session["AccessLevel"]);
    }
    set
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["AccessLevel"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: if the session is null again I will get the same error on your first line of code !

Comment: You can omit the String.IsNullOrEmpty call since empty strings and null values would still return a false when testing 'val=="2"'

Comment: `Convert.ToString`  wil never throw error, If the value come null in the `session variable` the same null value will be returned to the String variable. Did you test the above mentioned code ?

Comment: By your code I don't get the error message I mentioned before but there is still one problem : I don't have the session value either !

Comment: I mean , I don't kno why is that the session value becomes null on postback ! that's still the question !

Comment: @khashayar, Please share the code to assign the value to `Session` variable.

Comment: Nobody knows why the session becomes null ?!

Comment: `Request.Cookies["AccessLevel"].Value` might have `Nullable` value. Thus assigning null value to the `Session`

Comment: I don't think so , cause if it was that way on the first page load I would'nt have been loged in !

Comment: @khashayar - All I can say is you need to debug for the session value right after it gets the value and by the time it sets to null.

Comment: @khashayar - If you want to debug, make sure you have `Session_start and end` events in `global.asax` file. This will help you to track down the actual root cause. Just set `breakpoints` in these two events to minutely check the root cause of this issue.

Comment: @Guest I think I found out why my sessions become null ! when I want to save info about a book in db and save an image file of the book in an app folder , I don't have the permission to save the file and my application throws an error and all my sessions get null !!!

Comment: thank you :)))) , I think after uploading this website on a host I won't have this problem there cause I will give permission to the Images folder for file writing and this exception won't happen .

Answer (score 0):

> Why am I getting this error?

Because `Session["AccessLevel"]` is Null and you're attempting to call a method on a Null object.

Answer (score 0):

For other users, check your session timeout. may be it is the problem. you can change the default timeout using

```
<system.web>
   <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms timeout="50"/>
   </authentication>

   <sessionState timeout="60"  />
</system.web>
```