# response redirect makes session_end in global asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-3.5, response.redirect

I am getting frustrated due to the session become null.
When I click on save button I save the data to DB from code behind and if this successfully I am redirecting the user to the main projects page,using syntax:

```
Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Projects.aspx?i=esc&prjName=abc",'false');
```

but its make my session null.
Its goes to Globex.asax page ang executes the `Session_End` and make all session null.

I even tried `Server.Transfer` but by this the browser url remains same and client doesn't want this.Even some where I read that the `Server.Execute` is also used to redirect but it is showing some wrong results.

can I use the `Response.Redirect` without this session null problem ??

(In this page I am creating the text file to store some long description and if this is successful then I am redirecting to the another page.)

**Update::**

here is my code for button click

```
protected void lnkbtnAddDescription_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((!hidProjId.Value.ToString().Equals("") || !hidEditProjId.Value.ToString().Equals("")) && !txtDescription.Value.ToString().Equals(""))
                {
                    //ProjectDescription
                    int projId = 0;
                    if (!hidIsEdit.Value.ToString().Equals(""))
                    {
                        projId = Convert.ToInt32(hidEditProjId.Value.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        projId = Convert.ToInt32(hidProjId.Value.ToString());
                    }

                    ProjectM proj = new ProjectM();
                    proj.LoadByKey(projId);

                    string prj = proj.ProjectName.ToString().Replace(" ", "-");

                    string strDirectoryPath = Server.MapPath("~/ProjectDescription/") + proj.ProjectId + "-" + prj;
                    if (!Directory.Exists(strDirectoryPath))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(strDirectoryPath);

                        string filePath = strDirectoryPath + "/" + proj.ProjectId + "-" + prj + ".txt";
                        string strDescription = txtDescription.Value.ToString().Replace("<br />", "<p>");
                        createTextFile(filePath, strDescription);

                        string dbDirectoryPath = "~/ProjectDescription/" + proj.ProjectId + "-" + prj + "/" + proj.ProjectId + "-" + prj + ".txt";
                        proj.Description = dbDirectoryPath.ToString();
                        proj.IsNew = false;
                        proj.Save();

                        if (!hidIsEdit.Value.ToString().Equals(""))
                        {
                            //Server.Execute("~/SuperAdmin/Projects.aspx?i=esc&prjName=" + proj.ProjectName.ToString() + "",false);
                            Session["dsProj"] = null;
                            Session["editProjId"] = null;
                            Session["fname"] = hidFname.Value.ToString();
                            Session["UserId"] = hidUserId.Value.ToString();
                            Session["role"] = hidRole.Value.ToString();
                            Response.Redirect("~/SuperAdmin/Projects.aspx?i=esc&prjName=" + proj.ProjectName.ToString());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Server.Execute("~/SuperAdmin/Projects.aspx?i=sc&prjName=" + proj.ProjectName.ToString() + "",false);
                            Session["dsProj"] = null;
                            Session["editProjId"] = null;
                            Session["fname"] = hidFname.Value.ToString();
                            Session["UserId"] = hidUserId.Value.ToString();
                            Session["role"] = hidRole.Value.ToString();
                            Response.Redirect("~/SuperAdmin/Projects.aspx?i=sc&prjName=" + proj.ProjectName.ToString());
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Directory.Delete(strDirectoryPath, true);
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(strDirectoryPath);

                        string fileName = proj.ProjectName.ToString().Replace(" ", "-");

                        string filePath = strDirectoryPath + "/" + proj.ProjectId + "-" + fileName + ".txt";
                        string strDescription = txtDescription.Value.ToString().Replace("<br>", "<p>");
                        createTextFile(filePath, strDescription);

                        string dbDirectoryPath = "~/ProjectDescription/" + proj.ProjectId + "-" + proj.ProjectName.ToString() + "/" + proj.ProjectId + "-" + proj.ProjectName.ToString() + ".txt";
                        proj.Description = dbDirectoryPath.ToString();
                        proj.IsNew = false;
                        proj.Save();

                        if (!hidIsEdit.Value.ToString().Equals(""))
                        {
                            //Server.Execute("~/SuperAdmin/Projects.aspx?i=esc&prjName=" + proj.ProjectName.ToString() + "", false);
                            Session["dsProj"] = null;
                            Session["editProjId"] = null;
                            Session["fname"] = hidFname.Value.ToString();
                            Session["UserId"] = hidUserId.Value.ToString();
                            Session["role"] = hidRole.Value.ToString();
                            Response.Redirect("~/SuperAdmin/Projects.aspx?i=esc&prjName=" + proj.ProjectName.ToString());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Server.Execute("~/SuperAdmin/Projects.aspx?i=sc&prjName=" + proj.ProjectName.ToString() + "", false);
                            Session["dsProj"] = null;
                            Session["editProjId"] = null;
                            Session["fname"] = hidFname.Value.ToString();
                            Session["UserId"] = hidUserId.Value.ToString();
                            Session["role"] = hidRole.Value.ToString();
                            Response.Redirect("~/SuperAdmin/Projects.aspx?i=sc&prjName=" + proj.ProjectName.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }

        private void createTextFile(string filePath, string strDescription)
        {
            try
            {   
                StreamWriter w = File.CreateText(filePath);
                w.WriteLine(strDescription);
                w.Flush();
                w.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't thing the error is due to Response.Redirect there is some other problem

Comment: are you putting second argument in single quotes???

Comment: ohhh no its my writing mistake the correct one is: `Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Projects.aspx?i=esc&prjName=abc",false);`

Answer (score 0):

Before you redirect to the next page,
assign the existing session value in the button click event also.

This would solve the problem.

Comment: thanks for quick reply,but u mean to say `Session["id"] = Session["id"]` before redirect will solve it ??

Comment: No,it should be of session[id]=object.(assign whatever values you want to place it)

Comment: I have done this and test but I m getting the same error.If you want then you can check the code also.

Answer (score 0):

hope this will be helpful to you,
[ASP.NET Session becomes null after postback on local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434746/asp-net-session-becomes-null-after-postback-on-local)

This think your problem is related to some kind of permission denial, which is `nulling` your session.

Comment: and for that what I need to handle or set ?Plz guide me.

Comment: Grant permission to create directories and files (read/write/modify/...) to the parent directory of where you want to create the new directories...in your IIS manager..

Answer (score 0):

There must be a problem in creating or saving the text file. 
This may be making Session_End call so you are getting all values null.

Comment: but how text file save or create will affect the session?
this is just sake of knowledge

Comment: Sometimes if application throws any internal error, it makes session_end call. Maybe you are not having permission to create or save the file which is making application throwing error. Please check if your file is created/ saved successfully. If so then there might be some other reason fort he problem.

Answer (score -1):

Folder delete, move, rename causes Session end and long refresh

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/file-explorer/folder-delete-move-rename-causes-session-end-and-long-refresh.aspx#1365780

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.